# Why can't I download this file from Firebase Storage even though the file is there?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-storage

I'm getting the error below. Seems like it can't find the file, but I used the `listAll()` function to check and I see the file in the location.

```
Future<void> downloadMyApp(String MyAppURL) async { 
    final storagePath = await _firebaseStorage.ref().child('MyApp/Groups/groupChats/0exUS3P2XKFQ007TIMmm').listAll();

    for (var item in storagePath.items) {
      // The items under storageRef.
      print('##MyApp## downloadMyApp item: ' + item.toString()); //I see the item here and its path is identical to MyAppURL
    }

    final MyAppRef = _firebaseStorage.ref().child(MyAppURL);
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final filename = dir.path + receivedMyAppsDir + '/' + MyAppRef.name; 
    final file = File(filename);

    try {
      final downloadTask = MyAppRef.writeToFile(file);
      downloadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((taskSnapshot) {
        switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
          case TaskState.running:
            print('##MyApp## downloadMyApp downloadTask running');
            break;
          case TaskState.paused:
            print('##MyApp## downloadMyApp downloadTask paused');
            break;
          case TaskState.success:
            print('##MyApp## downloadMyApp downloadTask success');
            break;
          case TaskState.canceled:
            print('##MyApp## downloadMyApp downloadTask canceled');
            break;
          case TaskState.error:
            print('##MyApp## downloadMyApp downloadTask error');
            break;
        }
      });
    } catch (e) { //on FirebaseException
      // Caught an exception from Firebase.
      print('##MyApp## downloadMyApp ERROR: ' + e.toString());
    }

  }
```

```
E/FileDownloadTask(30544): Exception occurred during file write.  Aborting.
E/FileDownloadTask(30544): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(FileDownloadTask.java:136)
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(FileDownloadTask.java:228)
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FileDownloadTask(30544):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
E/StorageException(30544): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(30544): An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
E/StorageException(30544):  Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
E/StorageException(30544): No such file or directory
E/StorageException(30544): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
E/StorageException(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(FileDownloadTask.java:136)
E/StorageException(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(FileDownloadTask.java:228)
E/StorageException(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
E/StorageException(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
E/StorageException(30544): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(30544): An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
E/StorageException(30544):  Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
E/StorageException(30544): No such file or directory
E/StorageException(30544): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
E/StorageException(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(FileDownloadTask.java:136)
E/StorageException(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(FileDownloadTask.java:228)
E/StorageException(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
E/StorageException(30544):  at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/StorageException(30544):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
E/flutter (30544): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred
E/flutter (30544):
```

Comment: firebase storage has rules u have to edit them to allow read/write access

Comment: @trinadhthatakula I set my storage to be open to any read/writes using `allow read, write: if true;`

Comment: The error is during file **write**. Double-check that **filename** is correct. My guess is that you are building **filename** incorrectly.

Comment: @JohnHanley The path of filename is `/data/user/0/com.example.MyApp_3/app_flutter/MyApp/MyAppAudioFiles/ReceivedMyApps/f7e5dd33-ed66-40e7-9f86-2957cfcae917High.mp3`. The first part of my code shows how I build this filename.

Comment: You must verify that every part of that path is valid. A simple test is to use the command **touch <that_file_path>**. If that command fails, you know the problem. If that command succeeds, then my guess was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, when I followed the [Download to a local file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/download-files#download_to_a_local_file) docs directly, I had make make a change to how the file was being saved. I found the target file location needed to be modified from what the docs had:

Instead of:

```
final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final filePath = "${appDocDir.absolute}/images/island.jpg";
```

I changed it to:

```
final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final filePath = "${appDocDir.absolute.path}/images/island.jpg";
```

The issue is that `appDocDir.absolute` returns a `Directory` class, not a `String`